# What does it mean "The closing tag for the block will include the immediately trailing newline if one is present"?

Tags: php

I am learning to php from php.net but i am confused with the sentence **The closing tag for the block will include the immediately trailing newline if one is present.** at [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php).

Can anyone tell me what does it says, what is mean by **if one is present** in this sentence **The closing tag for the block will include the immediately trailing newline if one is present.** ?

You will see that sentence line at the end of the first paragraph at [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php)

Comment: If there is a newline character it will be included.

Comment: New line inside php closing tag or outside php closing tag ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The closing tag for the block will include the immediately trailing
>   newline if one is present.

Meaning, ?>\n is taken as the block closing delimiter, and both are removed from the final output. I expect this is to remove unnecessary blank lines in code like this:

```
<ul>
<?php foreach (..) ?>
    <li>..</li>
```

However, it does make it hard to control output of newlines.

## EDIT

Example: if you run

```
hello

there
<?php echo 'bye'; ?>

<?php echo 'there'; ?>
```

It prints

```
hello

there
bye
there
```

instead of

```
hello

there
bye

there
```

Ignoring the space there is between `<?php echo 'bye'; ?>` and `<?php echo 'there'; ?>`

*Note: If you want you can use `(?> <br>)` to output the blank line but this will also output the space between `>` and `<`*

Comment: You mean they are saying about those new lines that are outside the closing tag of php ?

Comment: @SunnyKhan Edited with an example

Comment: Ok this line say that let suppose you have 2 php blocks and between these two blocks there are unwanted lines added by the person. So when php interpreter interprets these two block, it will remove the closing tag of first php block and starting tag of second block and also unwanted spaces and lines between them, and will make it a single block. Is m right ?

Comment: It will remove spaces and lines between them, yes.

Comment: And will make it a single block by removing the closing tag of first php block and opening tag of second php block or not only spaces and lines will be removed and php 2 block will be remain ? ha ?

Comment: they will stay as two separate blocks

Comment: I have practice on it but it returns (Hello \n Bye) of this code <?php echo 'Hello' ?> \n
<?php echo 'Bye' ?>. Can you tell why ?

Comment: you're trying to pass `\n` as html try to pass `<br>` instead and let me know if it works

Comment: But in your answer you said that if you want new line you should use  (?> \n). You provided that in the end as a **Note**, please take a look at your answer above.

Comment: Now please do your correction and also clear my concept.